# endpoint para filtrar post por custom taxonomy

Tags: jquery, json

Então estou desenvolvendo um we app, e preciso filtrar os posts por taxnomia ao parecido com o esse get abaixo.

https://usevida.com.br/site/wp-json/wp/v2/post_type?custom_taxonomy=result

https://usevida.com.br/site/wp-json/wp/v2/estabelecimentos?cidade=niteoi

Comment: Olá Stefanny, sem o código que já desenvolveu até então, não obterá ajuda no site. Veja isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score -1):

eu consegui já obrigada!
ficou assim
https://usevida.com.br/site/wp-json/wp/v2/estabelecimentos?estabelecicidade=90&desconto=14

eu precisava usar a id da taxonomia ao invés do nome!